# How can I get mother table and daughter table results only with their row ID?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, syntax-error

I have one mother table person and 3 daughters tables : employee, prospect, visitor.

I'm trying to build a stored function to get the mother table and daughter table results only with their ID's, but I'm getting the same syntax error and I didn't find any solution yet.

CATEG here mean category, this is the way I know to which table I need to join the results with the person table.

```
drop function if exists get_person_and_subtable(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_person_and_subtable(IN id integer)
RETURNS SETOF record 
AS $fun$

DECLARE var_categ CHAR(5); 
DECLARE var_id INT = id;

BEGIN
    var_categ := (select PER_CATEG from T_PERSONNE where PER_ID = var_id);
    IF var_categ ='EMP' THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM T_PERSONNE INNER JOIN T_EMPLOYE ON T_PERSONNE.PER_ID = T_EMPLOYE.EMP_ID;
    ELSE IF  var_categ ='PROSP' THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM T_PERSONNE INNER JOIN T_PROSPECT ON T_PERSONNE.PER_ID = T_PROSPECT.PROSP_ID;
    ELSE RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM T_PERSONNE INNER JOIN T_VISITEUR ON T_PERSONNE.PER_ID = T_VISITEUR.VIS_ID; 
END;
$fun$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm using a PostgreSQL database.

Here is a translation of the error message :

ERROR: ERROR: syntax error on or near « ; »
LINE 15: END;

I tried different minor syntax changes, but it didn't work.

Comment: None of the `IF`s have corresponding `END IF`s. The `ELSE`s are also unnecessary since each `IF` terminates the function with a `RETURN` when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the ELSE and added END IF; at the end of each IF statement. So, now I have a new syntax error near : LANGUAGE plpgsql; Do you have any idea how to solve it?